# Get length of array with condition on attribute

Tags: twig, symfony

I'd like if is it possibel to get length of array with condition on attribute without create another query in the controller.

```
public function pageAction()
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $pages = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Page')->findAll();
    return $this->render(':Frontend/includes:menu.html.twig', array(
        'pages' => $pages
    ));
}
```

in the view

```
//number of all pages
{{ pages|length }} // output 15 (ok)
```

now is it possible to get the number of pages where **page.activate == true** from the same result returned in the controller ?

```
// number of page where page.activate == true
 ??
```

Comment: You can just use findBy instead of findAll.

Comment: Is `activate` an attribute or a row of the DB? Also do you have a getter for it? What's the getter?

Comment: @AlvinBunk yes it's a  row in the data base wth type boolean
`public function getActivate()
    {
        return $this->activate;
    }`

Comment: @MateuszSip , finByActivate will select only the activated page not all pages , so It must be two queries ?

Comment: If you really want to avoid queries, use [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) for that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work hous:

```
{% set pageCount = 0 %}{# Sets variable #}
{% for p in pages if p.getActivate %}
    {% set pageCount = pageCount + 1 %}
{% endfor %}

<p>Activated Pages: {{ pageCount }}
```

Try it!

Comment: Why this logic is in the view template, instead of a service or at least the controller? Or, for example, custom twig function would be good candidate to move the logic out.

Comment: @pavlovich , the code of Alvin works good but if you have an exemple how to make it out of the view template ? can you help me ?

Comment: Hous, I'm not actually sure what you are asking for? I thought you just wanted to print out the number of Activated pages? Can you explain in more detail what you need exactly please.